How to properly define a set of functions?
Is it correct to define a set of functions as
$\mathcal{F}=\{x, y\}, \quad \mathcal{F}: \Phi\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2K}$
where both $x$ and $y$ are functions defined on a bounded set $\Phi$ with codomain in $\mathbb{R}^K$?
Moreover, after $\mathcal{F}$ is formally defined, is the use of notation $\mathcal{F}(\phi)$ to represent the aggregation of both values appropriate?

Your notation doesn't make sense. The first statement says that $\mathcal{F}$ is a set of 2 objects while the second statement says that $\mathcal{F}$ is a function.
If you want to define two functions $x$ and $y$ from $\Phi$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2K}$, you can write
$$ x,y: \Phi \to \mathbb{R}^{2K} $$
For the last part of your question, I don't know what you mean by "aggregation". If you mean the set of values taken by both $x$ and $y$, you could write $x(\Phi) \cup y(\Phi)$.

The idea was to define a "function-like" entity $\mathcal{F}$ where $\mathcal{F}(\phi) = {x(\phi),y(\phi)}$, defined on the same domain of both functions and with co-domain $\mathbb{R}^{K\times 2}$; I'm not sure if that's what the union of both functions would imply.

I'm still not sure that I understand what you are trying to do with $\mathcal{F}$.  Writing $\mathcal{F}(\phi) = {x(\phi), y(\phi)}$ is certainly a valid definition. It would be a function $\mathcal{F}$ with domain $\Phi$ which returns a set of 2 points in $\mathbb{R}^{2K}$ (only 1 point if they are equal). But I don't know if that's what you want.

It's just an attempt to simplify notation, $x$ and $y$ are "coupled" variables (arguments are always the same) and this would allow me to declare top-level structure e.g.  $[\mathcal{F}_1~\mathcal{F}_2~\cdots~\mathcal{F}_N]$.
